# Query to read a column and use corresponding data in another column dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table as below:

[image]

I joining this table(Lets say **Location**) with another table(Lets say **Name**) on column C.

I want to be able to print the concatenation of Column A values  in my query *Country/State/Lane/Address/Suburb* .

The flow should be like this. Lets say there is a column value match E(with **Names**) table. Then the query looks up for corresponding value in column B, which is "D" in this case. Now it searches for value "D" in ColumnC and gets corresponding value in ColumnB which is "C". This continues until the value in column B is null. Once we get to that point, concatenate the Column A values for all the rows retrieved and display it *Country/State/Lane/Address/Suburb* .

I understand that this will probably require a dynamic query but I am not sure how do I join two tables and use dynamic query for only 1.

Comment: And what address do you want?

Comment: Do you mean you have different parts of the address in different rows in a location table? Please try and explain your schema a little better.

Comment: Does my post make more sense now? @TomC yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a recursive CTE:

First set up the data in a temp table:

```
declare @t table(A varchar(100), B varchar(10), C varchar(10))
insert @t values ('Address','C','D'),('Lane','B','C'),('Suburb','D','E'),('State','A','B'),('Country',null,'A')
```

Declare a start point

```
declare @start varchar(10); set @start='E'
```

Run the recursive query

```
;with cte as(
    select A, B from @t where C=@start
    union all
    select convert(varchar(100),T.A+'/'+cte.A), T.B 
    from cte
    join @t T on T.C=cte.B
)
select * from cte where B is null
```

Comment: The values I have provided are sample values. The table itself had lot more rows, so I am not sure if inserting each row will work as a solution :(

Comment: That is just to create your sample data to build an test the query. In your case substitute `Location` which is all the information you gave, for my temporary table @t.